# Problems with footer in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

In my page footer, I've created a `div`, but I'm having a problem with scroll bars.

My div code:

```
<div style="background-color:#4C73B3; height:25px; width:100%; text-align: center; position:fixed; bottom:0;">
OLOLO - 2014.
</div>
```

In this example the, `div`, I'm trying to remove the scroll bars and keep my div in the bottom of the page.

I tried to use relative positions, but it didn't workd.

I tried also to use absolute position but my div stayed in the top of the page

Someone have ideas?

Comment: Please try to change: position:fixed to position:relative

Comment: So: You want a footer that is displayed below all your other content and is only visible if you scroll down to the very bottom of your page?

Comment: problem still present, because if i set position:relative they pushed my div to the top site, don't know why...
that's why i asked you guys

Comment: Sumurai8 - that's right

Comment: it sounds like you don't need "position" at all. Take it out. The footer should be at the bottom of your content all by itself.

Comment: tried... didn't help too
again push to the top of site

Comment: why would a footer push the top of the site? where is it placed anyway? do you have a css for div? aside from the inline mentioned?

Comment: i don't know why)
i write this text in the bottom of all html text, after this div only </body>

Comment: any jsfiddle available?

Comment: Have you got a `<div id="container">`? If yes, put this div inside it.

Comment: i'm recheck all css, and didn;t find any css for div

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle with the whole page on it as there is obviously something going on in the page contents and it's impossible to know what it is from what you've posted here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
<div id="footer" style="background-color:#4C73B3;clear:both; height:25px; width:100%; text-align: center;">
ololo -  2014.
</div>
```

As you can see, the problem was the div needed to clear all floats.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the floats for the div is a solution.

Another one is to use the HTML5 [footer tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--Html-->    
<div class="page-wrap">

      <h1>Sticky Footer</h1>
      <h2>with Fixed Footer Height</h2>

      <button id="add">Add Content</button>  

    </div>

    <footer class="site-footer">
      I'm the Sticky Footer.
    </footer>



<!--Css-->
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
    margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
    height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}

<!-- JS-->
$("#add").on("click", function() {
  $("<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>").appendTo(".page-wrap");
});
```